# How to set the Vercel deployment TTL (time-to-live)?

Tags: vercel

1. What is the TTL for a deployment in NextJS Vercel from a Git branch?
2. How can I configure the TTL?

I looked through https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/overview but I couldn't see anything.